# Why is the z-index not working in my code?

Tags: z-index

My z-index in CSS is not working. My fixed header becomes invisible as soon as I scroll over another container. Then I wanted to increase the z-index, but it doesn't work.

I want my fixed header to no longer become invisible as soon as I scroll over a container. Here is my code:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
   
    height: 95px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.813);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

z-index does NOT work on fixed-positioned items.

Alternatively, you can make a child inside the header, and set the z-index on that.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how do I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but fixed position elements are indeed affected by `z index` property values. So your claim that it doesn't work is incorrect.